# Windows CHMOD 600

Tags: windows, permissions, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to Amazon EC2 using OpenSSH in windows but I need to set the permissions of my key file.

What is the windows equivalent of `CHMOD 600`?

I've googled extensively and found only blogspam.

EDIT: Windows 7, using DOS.

Comment: It's read-only for a specific user, I believe. I don't think it matters if the user can write to the file.

Comment: My calculation says rw for owner, everything else off.

Comment: surely you mean `chmod` rather than `CHMOD` too!!

Comment: right, but what is the command?

Comment: @David case-insensitive filesystem...

Comment: @Austin case-insenstive *nix? Really? Which one?

Comment: It's windows, you *must* use a gui </tongueincheek>. File properties, security, change it to owner only access.

Comment: You could even run `chmod` on Windows!

Comment: @david you need cygwin. Mac OS defaults to case insensitive

Comment: @Erik can you be more specific? There are a lot of different dialogs when I try to change permissions.

Comment: @Austin you don't need cygwin to run chmod.

Comment: @david it says "the program can't start because cygintl-2.dll is missing from the computer..." when I type `chmod`

Comment: @auston you need a native `chmod` rather than the cygwin one, e.g. [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Austin Also, what is DOS? Windows 7 has no DOS.

Comment: Exactly the same scenario has brought me here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really answering the same question but I was able to connect to EC2 using these instructions:

[SSH to EC2 linux instance from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264945/ssh-to-ec2-linux-instance-from-windows)

Answer (score 34):

I ran into the same problem on windows 10. I fixed it by doing the following steps.

1:- Right-click on the target file and select `properties` then select `Security` Tab

2:- Click `Advanced` and then make sure inheritance is disabled.

3:- Click `apply` and then click `Edit` in the security menu

4:- `Remove` all users except Admin user, which should have full control
*Admin account should have all checkboxes checked on `Allow` column except
special permission.

5:- Click `Apply` and then click OK.

You are good to go.
This worked for Amazon EC2 `.pem` file and gave almost the same working as Chmod 600 on Linux.

[image]

Comment: You're the one! Thanks! Removing all users except mine fixed it, ty.

Answer (score 30):

I realize this is somewhat old but I just found the solution for myself in Windows 7. And it  looks like this question went unresolved. I had all of the same errors including `Cygwin missing cygintl-2.dll` on `chmod` as you noted in the comments.

After extensive research and not finding any answers I ran:

```
C:\Users\mztriz\.ssh>ssh -v
```

> OpenSSH_3.8.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7d 17 Mar 2004
>       usage: ssh [-1246AaCfghkNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
>                  [-D port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-i identity_file]
>                  [-L port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-o option]
>                  [-p port] [-R port:host:hostport] [user@]hostname [command]

As you can see the version of OpenSSH I was running was quite outdated. However, I didn't know this because a quick google search of  `OpenSSH for Windows` returns this old version.

After looking into the versioning I found [OpenSSH for Windows 6.9p1-1](http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html) in the downloads section of that website.

This newer version of OpenSSH seems to fix all of the issues you mention.

Comment: (+1) Uninstalled the 0.9.7d version of OpenSSH and followed the instructions in this post to install a new OpenSSH. `chmod` works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Internet hasn't learned about http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html yet.

Comment: I had problems with AWS requiring me to enter a passphrase, which is not applicable. This was the only solution.

Answer (score 12):

Right-click on the file/dir, select Properties then Security. Click Advanced, then Edit. Uncheck "Inheritable" and choose "Remove" in the dialog. Remove any explicit permissions left, add a "Full Access" permission to your username.

Comment: it still says `Permissions 0644 for key.pem are too open`

Comment: Then openssh is not behaving nice - perhaps use cygwin instead?

Comment: Also, it *may* help to grant permissions to "Creator Owner" instead of your username.

Comment: This doesn't help the problem at all. The 0644 permission error still occurs.

Comment: One more step: Add an Entry for special user Everyone and edit the permissions for that user to Deny for all permissions

Comment: If you are in wsl, try putting it in `~/.ssh` and then `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` along with a `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/KeyPairName.pem`

That did it for me

Comment: Easy peasy fix on Win10. Thanks!

Comment: This pretty much did it for me. There was one file in `~/.ssh` that was messed up. I originally thought the problem file was `~/.ssh/config` but I also needed to check permissions on `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 12):

As an analogue of `chmod` in Windows, you can use the `icacls` command.

Equivalent of `chmod 600 <filename>` in windows will be:

```
# Add explicit R+W permissions for current user.
icacls <filename> /grant %username%:rw
# Disable inheritance from folders
icacls <filename> /inheritance:d
# Remove default groups (Authenticated Users, System, Administrators, Users)
icacls <filename> /remove *S-1-5-11 *S-1-5-18 *S-1-5-32-544 *S-1-5-32-545
```

To check current permissions:
`icacls <filename>`

Reset all permissions to default:
`icacls <filename> /reset`

Comment: This is the only correct answer guys, wake up! 
Only here we have the command to be used in the Windows CLI (DOS command prompt). 
Austin was very clear, he needs the command in DOS.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked like charm after removing the inheritance and deleting the other users.

Answer (score 11):

Modify the permissions so that:

- The key file doesn't inherit from the container
- You (the owner) have full access
- Remove permission entries for any other users (e.g., SYSTEM, Administrator)
- Add an Entry for special user *Everyone* and edit the permissions for that user to Deny for all permissions:

  - Right click on the file in Windows Explorer and choose Properties > Security > Advanced, to get the Advanced Security Settings dialog.
  - Click on the Permissions tab, then click Change Permissions.
  - Click Add, enter Everyone into the object name field, click Check Names, then click OK.
  - In the Permission Entry dialog, click the checkbox in the Deny column for Full Control.
  - Click OK on each dialog to back out and close the file's properies dialog.

Now scp will read permissions 0400 and will be happy. Ish.

Comment: Deny overrules separate User permissions - so if your Owner is in the Everyone group this will deny all permissions to that file and not result in 400 but in 000

Answer (score 8):

### For unix & OSX

Quite simply:

```
chown -R $USER:users ~/.ssh/
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/
```

### For Windows

*If the file is a windows (NTFS) symbolic link, the above won't work. You need to make it a regular file. I am not sure why.*

If you don't have openssh or cygwin, use chocolatey to install it easily using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

```
choco install cyg-get
```

**Open Cygwin Terminal** that was installed with chocolatey and run (note that `ssh-keygen` creates new keys):

```
cyg-get install openssh
ssh-keygen
cd ~/.ssh && explorer.exe .
```

Verify keys are there (or replace them with the keys you want), and then in Cygwin shell:

```
chown -R $USER:users ~/.ssh/
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/
```

Or for the rare case that you're using (and generated the keys from) **chocolatey's SSH** package:

```
chown -R $USER:users  /cygdrive/c/Users/$USER/.ssh
chmod -R 600 /cygdrive/c/Users/$USER/.ssh
```

Answer (score 6):

I've go same issue. The solution, which worked was to set compatibility mode of ssh.exe to Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Unfortunately this pops up UAC every time you run ssh and opens it in a new command shell (at least on Windows 8).

Answer (score 5):

chmod won't work in windows. Try the following method to restrict the access

- Right click on the file > properties > security > advanced > disable inheritance > 'Convert inherited permissions into explicit permission on this object'
- Click on "allow | everyone | Full Control" > edit > 'select a principal' > type your username > 'check names' > select your username > ok > ok > ok (ok until all windows are closed)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer **Cygwin** over **putty** and you can just run chmod command in cygwin to change the permission of PEM key to be 400, then you are good to go.

```
myuser@myuser-HP ~
$ ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/Downloads/mykey.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0550 for '/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/Downloads/mykey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/Downloads/mykey.pem": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).

myuser@myuser-HP ~
$ chmod
chmod: missing operand
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

myuser@myuser-HP ~
$ chmod 400 /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/Downloads/mykey.pem

myuser@myuser-HP ~
$ ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/Downloads/meykey.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.09-release-notes/
[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$ ohyeah I am in!
```

Answer (score 3):

Today one of the recommended ways on Windows would be to use PowerShell and the `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` Cmdlets.

Here's an example to ensure that only the current user has permission to a folder and all files in it - similar to what is recommended for the `.ssh` folder in Unix/Linux/OS X:

```
# get current ACL of directory
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Directory

# remove inheritance ($true) and remove all existing rules ($false)
$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)

# create new access rule for
# current user
# with FullControl permission
# enable inheritance for folders and files
# enable it for the specified folder as well
# allow these conditions 
$AcessRule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new(
    $env:USERNAME,
    "FullControl",
    ([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit),
    [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow)

# add access rule to empty ACL
$Acl.AddAccessRule($AcessRule)

# activate ACL on folder
Set-Acl -Path $Directory -AclObject $Acl
```

For more details see

- [FileSystemAccessRule-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Set-Acl documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

I've go same issue. The solution, which worked was to set compatibility mode of ssh.exe to Windows XP SP3.

-> This answer works for windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file to Unix system throug scp and make chmod 600 to file.
Then transfer file back to Windows machine.
It worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't fix the 0644 permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [Chao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work) helped me, because I have WSL installed on my Windows 10.

In WSL (Ubuntu on Windows) I opened a text editor with `sudo` and created the file `/etc/wsl.conf` with text in it:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Then rebooted my Windows.

Now I am able to edit file permissions in WSL: `chmod 0600` now works!

Answer (score 0):

I would have liked to comment the response from @GeniyX to complement it but I still cannot comment :(

FROM **@GeniyX**:

```
# Add explicit R+W permissions for current user.
# <> characters are not needed (the name of my pem is "JPCloud.pem"), also from %username%, the %% characters are not needed (my user us "Josepe", in my case it was like this: (first used cd command to go the folder) 
# icacls JPCloud.pem /grant Josepe:rw
icacls <filename> /grant %username%:rw

# Disable inheritance from folders
#nothing to add here, again <> characters are not needed
icacls <filename> /inheritance:d
# Remove default groups (Authenticated Users, System, Administrators, Users)
icacls <filename> /remove *S-1-5-11 *S-1-5-18 *S-1-5-32-544 *S-1-5-32-545
```

For those like me that were lost about the numbers at the end

(WHAT DO THE NUMBERS MEAN JASON???!"?!?)

well here is the anwser:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers
they are security identifiers:

S-1-5-11 is for authenticated users

S-1-5-18 is for LocalSystem

S-1-5-32-545    is for the default group of "admins"

S-1-5-32-545    is for the default group of "users"

The only thing I do not understand is the * at the beginning of each security identifier (but I imagine that is used to give more than 1 parameter to the command...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute all(other cmds scp etc.) in Git Bash

`chmod 600 file.pem`

worked for me on windows 11