# How to make a Password-Less Login from Windows to Linux using OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen

I installed the OpenSSH on my Windows 7 Machine. I want to connect to the remote Linux machine without typing password. I followed the bellow instructions but the SSH needs password to establish the connection yet.

1. Open CMD and run: ssh-keygen -t rsa (The public and private keys are generated in the C:\Users\user.ssh) folder
2. Copy the id_rsa.pub content into /home/kouhi/.ssh/authorized_keys in my Linux remote machine
3. In Linux Machine run: chmod 700 .ssh
4. In Linux Machine run: chmod 644 .ssh/authorized_keys

When I try to Ssh kouhi@remote.com the connection ask me the password yet. 
Also I tied Ssh -i C:\Users\user.ssh\id_rsa kouhi@remote.com

Also I get the following reply when run the ssh command:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'C:\\Users\\user\\id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: C:\\Users\\user\\id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264595/windows-chmod-600):

> Right-click on the [private key file], select Properties then Security. Click Advanced, then Edit. Uncheck "Inheritable" and choose "Remove" in the dialog. Remove any explicit permissions left, add a "Full Access" permission to your username.

Comment: Thanks, the permission error is disappeared now! But the connection needs password yet!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Open your windows powershell

Step 2 : Type command **ssh-keygen -t rsa**

Step 3 : Now a private and public is generated and we have to copy this
public key into the remote linux server.For that do the below
steps.
- Copy the public key stored  **C:\Users\User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**
(Don't copy through GUI as it will give error,use powershell
itself)

Step 4 : Now login to your remote server using your ID and password

Step 5 : Now paste the copied public key in **/.ssh/authorized_keys**
using vim editor.

Step 6 : Now login from your windows powershell without password

TIPS : Try ssh restart , clear your earlier generated keys in authorised key folder and id_rsa.pub if you get errors and do as fresh