# Permission for singularity

Tags: linux, singularity-container, nextflow

I am got an issue when running the whole pipeline of ChIP-seq using profile singularity on my local PC (window but subsystem Linux)

```
Error executing process > 'output_documentation' 
Caused by: 
Failed to pull singularity image 
command: singularity pull --name nfcore-chipseq-1.2.2.img.pulling.1630098407814 docker://nfcore/chipseq:1.2.2 > /dev/null 
status : 255 
message: 
INFO: Using cached SIF image 
FATAL: While making image from oci registry: error copying image out of cache: could not open temporary file for copy: failed to change permission of ./tmp-copy-2575820807: chmod ./tmp-copy-2575820807: operation not permitted
```

I'm using singularity 3.8.2
I also have specified `NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR` to a hard drive instead of `/home/.singularity`
I also checked the folder to make sure all the file can be accessed

```
total 0 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 28 05:06 . 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Aug 28 04:47 .. 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 28 04:53 tmp-copy-2299332276 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 28 05:06 tmp-copy-2575820807
```

Comment: This is a permissions problem not a Nextflow problem: `chmod ./tmp-copy-2575820807: operation not permitted`. You mentioned using WSL, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work

Comment: Also, you may prefer setting `singularity.cacheDir` in your nextflow.config instead of exporting `NXF_SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR`.