# Laravel API Authentication (Passport); ErrorException in CryptKey.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

ErrorException in CryptKey.php line 57:

Key file "file://C:\wamp\www\project\public_html\storage\oauth-private.key" permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 666

**My Configuration as follows:**

- Windows 10 64bit
- WampServer 3.1.0
- Apache 2.4.27
- PHP 7.0.23
- Laravel Framework version 5.3.31
- composer require laravel/passport=~1.0

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn off file checking permissions on line 57

your CryptKey Path is `vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php`

on line number 48 turn it to false or comment the following block in your `CryptKey.php`

```
   if ($keyPermissionsCheck === true) {
        // Verify the permissions of the key
        $keyPathPerms = decoct(fileperms($keyPath) & 0777);
        if (in_array($keyPathPerms, ['600', '660'], true) === false) {
            trigger_error(sprintf(
                'Key file "%s" permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of %s',
                $keyPath,
                $keyPathPerms
            ), E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    }
```

`keyPermissionsCheck` set it to false.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simply CHMOD the oauth-private.key file to 600 or 660. I see that you use Windows so you can surely follow the directions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264595/windows-chmod-600) to do that.