# Key file permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 644

Tags: file-permissions

Key file permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 644
How can I solve this?

Comment: This could also be a error when setting up a laravel project on Windows XAMP.

Answer (score 9):

As @avigil and @IliaRostovtsev mentioned on their answers. You have to change the file permisions to 600 or 660 with this instruction:

```
chmod 600 /filepath
```

or

```
chmod 660 /filepath
```

Why **600** or **660** instead of **644** permissions? Becase:

**644 permission means:** I (owner) can change it, everyone else can read it.

**600 permission means**: I (owner) can write and read the file, everyone else can't.

**660 permission means**: I (owner) can write and read the file. Group members can write and read the file. Everyone else not mentioned above can't.

**600 and 660 permissions** will add an extra level of **security** to your files because you won't let **"everyone"** to read or write on your files

If you have Windows and have trouble with laravel you can check these 2 links which fix this problem:

[Passport Laravel](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/issues/779)

[Passport Laravel 2](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/453)

Comment: C:\>chmod 600 \www\laravel\aapiVeiculos\storage\oauth-public.key
'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DecepcionadoZimmermann are you using windows?

Comment: @DecepcionadoZimmermann I suggest you to see this link: [Passport laravel](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/453)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, @DecepcionadoZimmermann I believe it's a correct answer

Comment: @MoeFar I'm glad it was usefull. Have a nice day

Comment: thank you it also worked for Drupal 8.

Comment: @StefanYYC Sorry to answer late. I'm glad it was useful for you too!

Answer (score 2):

Setting needed permissions by running in the console on the required file:

```
chmod 600 /path/to/the/file
```

Comment: C:\>chmod 600 \www\laravel\aapiVeiculos\storage\oauth-public.key
'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @DecepcionadoZimmermann What OS are you running it on?

Comment: estou usando o Windows

Comment: You should take a look here then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264595/windows-chmod-600

Answer (score 1):

Set proper permissions with `chmod 600 /path/to/your/keyfile`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do: `sudo chmod 660 filename`

Comment: if permissions are 644 and he is owner the `sudo` should not be necessary

Comment: Never hurts to use sudo when running a chmod, that way you ensure that whoever reads the answer doesn't get yet another error regarding permissions

Comment: Probably safer to `sudo chown $(whoami) filename` first in that case, since `sudo chmod 660` on a file not owned by the current user will still cause permissions issues later

Comment: Fair enough, that would probably be the safest way